# SAP GUI Scripting VBA - checking the Dynamic ID

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I want to write a code where the script selects the correct processes (e.g. `A07`) in the transaction MIGO in SAP GUI.

But apparently the `SAPLMIGO:0007` in the code below is dynamic and can change.

Is there a way that I can check the actual ID and use this in the line of code?

```vb
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0007/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").Key = "A07"
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the string `wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0007/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION`  contains `SAPLMIGO:0007` ?

Comment: @Storax :actually SAPLMIGO:0007 can change to SAPLMIGO:0003 instead for example and I want to be able to check it when opening the transaction so I'm able to integrate it. I've found this online but it isn't working sadly:
'Get name of GuiScrollContainer
`GSC = "wnd[0]/usr/ssub" & session.Children(0).Children(5).Children(1).Name`
'select Goods Receipt
`session.findById(GSC & "/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0010/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").Key = "A07"`

Comment: You can loop at the elements displayed in a screen (property `Children` available in all controls), so you can find the right ID easily. See [How to Detect UI Element ID with Regular Expressions in SAP GUI Scripting](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/06/28/how-to-detect-ui-element-id-with-regular-expressions-in-sap-gui-scripting/),

Comment: For you, the solution based on [How to Detect UI Element ID with Regular Expressions in SAP GUI Scripting](https://blogs.sap.com/2021/06/28/how-to-detect-ui-element-id-with-regular-expressions-in-sap-gui-scripting/) would be this code, where `0007` was replaced with `.*` : `session.findById(FindByIDPart(app, session.findById("wnd[0]/usr"), "ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:.*/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").Key = "A07"`. NB: in the blog post, there is a comment to convert VBScript into VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will return the ID of the object in question.

Let's assume `session` is a GUI session which points to a SAPGUI session with MIGO just started. Then `Debug.Print session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").Children(0).ID` will return you the complete ID like `/app/con[0]/ses[0]/wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0007`
You could now check the string for  `SAPLMIGO:` and return the part you are interested in.

```
Dim migoID
migoID = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").Children(0).ID

Dim pos
pos = InStr(1, migoID, "SAPLMIGO:", vbTextCompare)

migoID = Mid(migoID, pos, 13)
Debug.Print migoID
```

Comment: Storax, my man! Thank you  so much!!