# SAP MIGO Dynamic ID

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui, sap-erp

I also have this issue as described in the post: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764376/sap-gui-scripting-vba-checking-the-dynamic-id](https://stackoverflow.com)

I am trying to run a script in VBA from Excel to automatically run this T-code / transaction to remove an item (deallocate) from the BOM because it has a quality issue.

When the code runs I keep getting the 619 runtime error obviously because it cannot find the field I am referring to as the dynamic id has changed again from what was in the code (section SAPLMIGO:0003 becomes SAPLMIGO:0002 or something else).

I have multiple variables I am trying populate so I need to know if I can find each dynamic ID, how can I then refer to these in the code?

Here is the code in question:

```
'Populate Variables
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").Key = "A03" 'Select Cancellation and should default to Material Doc on next box
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/subSUB_FIRSTLINE_REFDOC:SAPLMIGO:2010/txtGODYNPRO-MAT_DOC").Text = "" 'clear the material doc
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/subSUB_FIRSTLINE_REFDOC:SAPLMIGO:2010/txtGODYNPRO-DOC_YEAR").Text = "" 'clear the date / year
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/subSUB_FIRSTLINE_REFDOC:SAPLMIGO:2010/txtGODYNPRO-MAT_DOC").Text = MatDoc 'Material Document
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/subSUB_FIRSTLINE_REFDOC:SAPLMIGO:2010/txtGODYNPRO-MAT_DOC").caretPosition = 1
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'Populate Date of previous fiscal year if issue was not in the same year
If InStr(Session.FindById("wnd[0]/sbar").Text, "Fiscal") <> 0 Then 'check that date is current year
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/subSUB_FIRSTLINE_REFDOC:SAPLMIGO:2010/txtGODYNPRO-DOC_YEAR").Text = Year(Date) - 1
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/subSUB_FIRSTLINE_REFDOC:SAPLMIGO:2010/txtGODYNPRO-DOC_YEAR").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/subSUB_FIRSTLINE_REFDOC:SAPLMIGO:2010/txtGODYNPRO-DOC_YEAR").caretPosition = 4
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
End If

Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0003/subSUB_ITEMDETAIL:SAPLMIGO:0301/btnBUTTON_ITEMDETAIL").press 'press item detail button to minimise (needs to be done to activate the check box)

Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0002/subSUB_ITEMLIST:SAPLMIGO:0200/tblSAPLMIGOTV_GOITEM/chkGOITEM-TAKE_IT[4,0]").Selected = True 'click check box
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0002/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL").Select

Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0002/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL/ssubSUB_TS_GOHEAD_GENERAL:SAPLMIGO:0112/ctxtGOHEAD-BLDAT").Text = Day(Date) & "." & Month(Date) & "." & Year(Date)
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0002/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL/ssubSUB_TS_GOHEAD_GENERAL:SAPLMIGO:0112/ctxtGOHEAD-BUDAT").Text = Day(Date) & "." & Month(Date) & "." & Year(Date)
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0002/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL/ssubSUB_TS_GOHEAD_GENERAL:SAPLMIGO:0112/ctxtGOHEAD-BUDAT").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssubSUB_MAIN_CARRIER:SAPLMIGO:0002/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0101/subSUB_HEADER:SAPLMIGO:0100/tabsTS_GOHEAD/tabpOK_GOHEAD_GENERAL/ssubSUB_TS_GOHEAD_GENERAL:SAPLMIGO:0112/ctxtGOHEAD-BUDAT").caretPosition = 10
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[7]").press
Session.FindById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have tried to use the code solution in the previous post but this just prints out migoID.  What do I do with this next?

Comment: Could you ask directly via comment in the answer you are referring to, please?

Comment: I am afraid but you do not populate any variables in your code. You just try to fill some fields in SAPGUI with some values resp. you clear them by assigning an empty string. And in the case you refer to an non-existing ID you will get  Run-Time Error 619. The other post is solely about obtaining the ID of the current MIGO screen. I fail to see how that information could be useful in this particular scenario

Comment: Sorry, this is just a snippet of the full code where some variables are passed.  I guess my key issue is I cannot select the correct SAP field because it is a dynamic ID.

What I need to try and figure out is how do i firstly identify what the dynamic ID is for the particular instance and then how do I adjust my code so it selects the items on the SAP screen based on the dynamic ID.  Does that make sense?  Sorry but I am quite a novice when it comes to this

Comment: @Storax like i say in my original post, this is like an issue you appear to have solved a few weeks ago with the following code: 
```Dim migoID migoID = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").Children(0).ID Dim pos pos = InStr(1, migoID, "SAPLMIGO:", vbTextCompare) migoID = Mid(migoID, pos, 13) Debug.Print migoID```
```
my issue with this code is that the line migoID = Mid(migoID, pos, 13) provides a runtime error 5. If we can resolve that, does the migoID become part of my string? for example
```Session.FindById(migoID&"/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").Key = "A03"```

Comment: @mick5003 Why don't you discuss directly at the place this was has answered, to obtain a more precise answer?

Comment: @SandraRossi sorry but I lacked the sufficient level to post a comment on the original post

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from the original poster (OP), I guess that the following code could be helpful. The assumption here is that the `session` variable refers to an already started SAPGUI MIGO session.”

```
Set guiUsr = session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr")
Set guiCon = guiUsr.Children(0)
guiCon.FindById("subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").key = "A03"
```

In such a way you are independent from the specific string.

You could rewrite that as `session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr").Children(0).FindById("subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").key = "A03"`

The post the OP referred to is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77764376/sap-gui-scripting-vba-checking-the-dynamic-id/77765227#77765227)

Comment: sorry but I still get a 619 error on the first line when I try to select "A03":
`'Run reverse MIGO transaction
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nMIGO"
Session.FindById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0

'Code to handle MIGO dynamic ID
Set guiUsr = Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr")
Set guiCon = guiUsr.Children(0)

'Populate Variables
guiCon.FindById("subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").Key = "A03"`

it would appear that it is still not finding the dynamic path

Comment: The code snippet you provided is working for me. I’m afraid, but I don’t know what could be different at your side. It appears that your company has customized the layout of MIGO in a different way.

Comment: Managed to find a solution that works for me
```
Set UserArea = Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr")
For i = 0 To UserArea.Children.Count - 1
  If InStr(UserArea.Children(CInt(i)).Name, "SAPLMIGO:") Then
    SubName = UserArea.Children(CInt(i)).Name
  End If
Next
Set SubArea = Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub" & SubName)


'Populate Variables

Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub" & SubName & "/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").SetFocus
Session.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/ssub" & SubName & "/subSUB_FIRSTLINE:SAPLMIGO:0011/cmbGODYNPRO-ACTION").Key = "A03"
```